# QGroupBox from Generated ui_*.h FIle is Represented as a Pointer to an Int -- Why?

Tags: c++, qt, generated

I'm working on an application which uses QtDesigner for part of its UI. QtDesigner .ui files are generally compiled to a .h representation that you can access from the rest of your QT code. For the most part it works, widgets that are laid out show pointers to widgets of the same type in code, but for certain elements (particularly `QGroupBox`) the generated ui code shows the `QGroupBox` objects as `int *`. I can access the contents of the QGroupBox normally by using `qobject_cast<QGroupBox *>` but I find it odd that it's not necessary for other UI elements that I need access to.

Is this the normal behavior for `QGroupBox` elements or any other QtDesigner widgets/layouts? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you could explain yourself better, because you point out that an `int *` is generated when you use `QGroupBox`, I just reviewed and generates `QGroupBox *` in `ui_xxx.h`

Comment: agree with @eyllanesc, please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. If it really occurs it sounds like a Qt bugs anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm going to chalk this up to a minor bug. Changing my build directory in project settings to something different and then back helped QT Creator find the proper type for the added UI elements.